# How can you make a object access the variables in a method without using .this?

Tags: java

By making the object in main function and calling its method and updating the variables from class.
example:

```
public class Test{
int a;
void testMethod(){
//how to access the variable here?
}
public static void main(String[] args){
Test Obj = new Test();
obj.testMethod();
}
```

How to access the variable 'a' inside the method testMethod without using .this ?

Comment: just write `a` ...

Answer (score 1):

You could access it in two ways:

a. Using `this` keyword as below:

```
System.out.println(this.a);
```

b. Directly using the variable as below:

```
System.out.println(a);
```

Choice depends on you. I'd personally prefer along with `this` as it's explicit (object variable as opposed to referring to method local variable) and help me in making code readable.